# DynamoDB - Most efficient way of deleting a partition?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Let's say I have a partition-key that is `User:user@email.com` and it has several sort-keys like `Data`, `Sale:001`, `Contact:001`.

Now, what if I want to delete this user?

I have thought of two possible ways using the API.

**1 - Scan**

First do a `SCAN` where `partition-key=User:user@email`, get the results and do a batch delete on each returned item with the respective sort-key.

**2 - Query**

For this I would first need to change all sort keys to have a common prefix, for example `User|Data`, `User|Sale:001`, `User|Contact:001`, and then do a query where

```
partition-key=User:user@email.com and sort_key.begins_with(User)
```

after getting the results I would then do a batch delete just like the scan option.

---

It isn't clear to me which option is the best because I'm not sure if the Scan has the "intelligence" to only scan inside that specific partition or it would scan every record in the table. Because in DynamoDB you pay for each kb of items that was "searched"

Because if it is intelligent then I think it would cost the same as the query option without needing to add a prefix to my sort keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan() doesn't support `partition-key=User:user@email` except as a filter expression.

So yes, the whole table would be read. Only the records that match would actually be returned.

Query() on the other hand requires `partition-key=user:user@email` as a key condition expression.  You don't need to make any changes to your sort key design; as including a key condition for the sort key is [optional](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html).

> The partition key equality test is required, and must be specified in
>   the following format:
>
> partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval
>
> **If you also want to provide a condition** for the sort key, it must be
>   combined using AND with the condition for the sort key. Following is
>   an example, using the = comparison operator for the sort key:
>
> partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval AND sortKeyName = :sortkeyval

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware the condition for the sort-key was optional